# PHPExcel_Writer_Exception in DomPDF.php line 34: Unable to load PDF Rendering library

Tags: laravel, pdf, dompdf, snappy

error in exporting to pdf. i tried composer update and adding stuffs to app.php anf composer.json

```html
 public function exportPDF($request, $orgid)
    {
        /*$pdf = App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
        return $pdf->inline();*/
       $data = User::get()->toArray();
       return Excel::create('itsolutionstuff_example', function($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($data);
        });
       })->download("pdf");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wich pdf renderer have you set up? Acording to the documentation, you have 3 choices, tcpdf, mPdf and DomPDF.
You have to install at least one of them.

```
composer require mpdf/mpdf
```

and then direct PHPExcel to use it

```
$renderer = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF;
$rendererPath = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../libraries/PDF/mPDF6.1'

if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
    $renderer,
    $rendererPath
    )) {
    die('Wrong setup of PDF libraries');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please comment this line in DomPDF.php

```
if (file_exists($pdfRendererClassFile)) {
    require_once $pdfRendererClassFile;
} else {
    throw new PHPExcel_Writer_Exception('Unable to load PDF Rendering library');
}
```

to

```
/**  Require DomPDF library */
//$pdfRendererClassFile = PHPExcel_Settings::getPdfRendererPath() . '/dompdf_config.inc.php';
//if (file_exists($pdfRendererClassFile)) {
//    require_once $pdfRendererClassFile;
//} else {
//    throw new PHPExcel_Writer_Exception('Unable to load PDF Rendering library');
//}
```

Hope it will works.